# How do I load the Oracle schema into memory instead of the hard drive?

Tags: oracle, memory, schema, performance, loader

I have a certain web application that makes upwards of ~100 updates to an Oracle database in succession. This can take anywhere from 3-5 minutes, which sometimes causes the webpage to time out. A re-design of the application is scheduled soon but someone told me that there is a way to configure a "loader file" which loads the schema into memory and runs the transactions there instead of on the hard drive, supposedly improving speed by several orders of magnitude. I have tried to research this "loader file" but all I can find is information about the SQL* bulk data loader. Does anyone know what he's talking about? Is this really possible and is it a feasible quick fix or should I just wait until the application is re-designed?

Comment: I think 'loader' is the wrong search term. Try for 'memory cache' or 'delayed write' or some such.

Comment: I have heard of people trying to cache tables by accessing them when their application starts, but I would suggest working on determining what is slow and working on fixing the exact issue. Oracle has already devoted much time and effort to algorithms that cache the most recently and frequently used data. Are you sure it is going to disk for these operations? Do you know the overhead of each round trip between your web application and the database? Can the updates be batched in any way? Have you checked StatsPack or AWR reports for top wait events?

Comment: lexu: Thanks for the heads up those search terms were much more helpful.

Comment: David Mann: Now that you mention it, I'm pretty sure the main bottleneck is the bad design of application which runs each update as a separate query instead of batching them as you suggest, and so any memory vs. disk optimization would be negligible compared to the overhead between the application and database.

Comment: You are correct Andrew. It sounds like it may be the fixed cost of overhead of a round trip between the app server and the database server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle already does it's work in memory - disk I/O is managed behind the scenes. Frequently accessed data stays in memory in the buffer cache. Perhaps your informant was referring to "pinning" an object in memory, but that's really not effective in the modern releases of Oracle (since V8), particularly for table data. Let Oracle do it's job - it's actually very good at it (probably better than we are). Face it - 100K updates is going to take a while.